# How can I change the android code to make it work again?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment-lifecycle

I am a android beginner who follows a book.now I have a problem.the test app is an news app and have code like this:

```
public class NewsTitleFragment extends Fragment implements OnItemClickListener {
    private ListView newsTitleListView;
    private List<News> newsList;
    private NewsAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        newsList = getNews();
        adapter = new NewsAdapter((Activity)activity, R.layout.news_item, newsList);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater
            .inflate(R.layout.news_title_frag, container, false);
        newsTitleListView = (ListView) view
            .findViewById(R.id.news_title_list_view);
        newsTitleListView.setAdapter(adapter);
        newsTitleListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        if (getActivity().findViewById(R.id.news_content_layout) != null) {
            isTwoPane = true;
        } else {
            isTwoPane = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {
        News news = newsList.get(position);
        if (isTwoPane) {
            NewsContentFragment newsContentFragment = (NewsContentFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.news_content_fragment);
            newsContentFragment.refresh(news.getTitle(), news.getContent());
        } else {
            NewsContentActivity.actionStart(getActivity(), news.getTitle(),
                news.getContent());
        }
    }

    private List<News> getNews() {
        List<News> newsList = new ArrayList<News>();
        News news1 = new News();
        news1.setTitle("It's news 1");
        news1.setContent("It's news 1 content");
        newsList.add(news1);
        News news2 = new News();
        news2.setTitle("It's news 2");
        news2.setContent("It's news 2 content");
        newsList.add(news2);
        return newsList;
    }

}
```

but in new android API,the code

```
public void onAttach(Activity activity)
```

must change to

```
public void onAttach(Context context)
```

I change it,but the app shows anything after change!
I want to know why i'm wrong and how to alter it.
Thanks a lot.
P.S.The class NewsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter.The class News has only two Strings
The NewsAdapter method is:

```
public class NewsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<News> {

    private int resourceId;

    public NewsAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<News> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        resourceId = textViewResourceId;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        News news = getItem(position);
        View view;
        if (convertView == null) {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(resourceId, null);
        } else {
            view = convertView;
}
    TextView newsTitleText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.news_title);
newsTitleText.setText(news.getTitle());
        return view;
        }

}
```

Comment: Your Fragment has no onCreateView method. So it's blank

Comment: It has already an onCreateView method.before the change the app shows news list,but when I change it to "Context" the apps shows nothing

Comment: We would like you to show a [mcve], so we can verify the problem. In other words, please [edit] to show that method

Comment: You also do not need `onAttach` to get a reference to the context/activity. You can call `getActivity()` within `onCreateView`

Comment: I solved it! thanks very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this in `onCreateView`

```
newsList = new ArrayList<News>();
adapter = new NewsAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.news_item, newsList);
newsTitleListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Instead of `newsList = getNews()`, use

```
adapter.clear(); // or newsList.clear();
adapter.addAll(getNews()); // or newsList.addAll();
/** ... but, if using alternatives **/
// adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // this is needed if not using adapter methods directly
```

Or, re-write `getNews()` to add directly to the adapter.

Then, don't re-assign the `adapter` or `newsList` outside of `onCreateView` because there is no need to.

Comment: Can you tell me why I should use `adapter.clear(); adapter.addAll(getNews());`but not `newsList = getNews()`? because of the code specification?

Comment: Because when you use `newsList = getNews()`, you are "detaching" the reference of the list that the adapter holds onto.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the Android Fragment Documentation https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html

As cricket_007 already mentioned you have to set or create the layout in the onCreateView Method and return it.

Example from the Fragment documentation:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ScrollView scroller = new ScrollView(getActivity());
    TextView text = new TextView(getActivity());
    int padding = (int)TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
            4, getActivity().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    text.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
    scroller.addView(text);
    text.setText(Shakespeare.DIALOGUE[getShownIndex()]);
    return scroller;
}
```

Or if you have already an XML Layout you can simply inflate them in the onCreateView method:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);
        return view;
}
```

Comment: I have XML and onCreateView method ,and before I change it to "Context" the app works well.After change it shows nothing